# How to type Ctrl-C (and others) in terminal emulator

Tags: applications

On Android 11, I tried in Terminal Emulator for Android and 'Material Emulator'. Pressing <kbd>Vol Dn</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> doesn't do anything.

For example, but not limited to, after

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

I can't find any way to stop the ping (except exiting the emulator, of course). Tried all kinds of combinations. Similarly, typing

```
$sort
a
b
c
```

How do I stop input? On Linux I'd type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (=eof), but that doesn't work on Android.

In `preferences`, I have `Vol Dn` as definition for the `Control Key`

**Note**: Thanks for the suggestions! What I'm worried about is that in the `Special Keys` help item, it clearly states that `Vol Dn` should act as a `Control` key (in both terminal emulators I tried). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: long touch for menu, or install termux, or hackers keyboard

Comment: Many keyboards can send Ctrl events including [AnySoftKeyboard](https://github.com/mirfatif/AnySoftKeyboard).

Comment: ping command accepts the count flag "-c " to limit the no. of echo requests

Comment: @crazo7924, I knew that... The issue is (was) more generic: There are quite a few commands that take input from `stdin`, but then it's generally necessary to end with `Ctrl-D` - same problem. It's difficult to live without a real Ctrl key! Anyway, tke `hackers kbd` solved things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To close this issue:

Thanks for the suggestions:

@alecxs: The [hackers keyboard](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) works great, and as it can represent a full keyboard, it feels very familiar. On screen portrait mode it's a bit more difficult to use though.

@IrfanLatif: [AnySoftKeyboard](https://github.com/mirfatif/AnySoftKeyboard) looks very promising as it's easier to use in portrait mode and has better access for foreign languages.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug for the recent versions  of Android, I hope the developer fix it ASAP because I really loved that terminal, but I tried this one and it worked well

[TermOne Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termoneplus)